# Can a private Cloud data fusion connect to the internet?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

Our application is made of a spring-bot app server deployed through *"cloud run"* and a *"cloud sql postgres"* database.

The database is private and connected to a *private VPC* .
The app server can connect to the database through a gateway to this private VPC provided by the "cloud run" configuration.

We'd like to feed this database with "cloud data fusion" (CDF) periodically.
CDF should fetch data from AWS S3 and push it into our database.

We've designed and validated a pipeline for that purpose but we're facing a network paradox :

- Either CDF is public, can read from S3 over internet, but can't reach the cloud database
- or CDF is private, can reach our database but can't reach internet for S3 fetching...

How can CDF both write **to the private** database and read data **from the internet** ?
I'm surprised that a CDF instance, even being private, can't establish an EGRES connection to an internet resouce.

Comment: Instances that do not have a public IP address require a Cloud NAT in the VPC to provide public Internet access. https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Data fusion is a tool that help you to build pipeline (based on [CDAP](https://github.com/cdapio/cdap)). If you set the Data Fusion private, it's the access to the tool that is private, not the runtime! On Google Cloud, the pipeline runs on [Dataproc cluster](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc).

So now, the question is: Can your Dataproc cluster reach internet and your database?

1. If your cluster run in the same VPC as your Cloud SQL database private IP connection, and there is no firewall rule that prevent the communication, it's OK
2. If your Compute Engines that compose your cluster have public IP, no problem, you can access to public URL. Else, as said by John Hanley, you can create a Cloud NAT to allow your Compute Engine to initiate call to external URL.

Comment: Yes, if you use serverless product such as cloud run, cloud function of App Engine, you need to create a bridge between the serverless world and your own VPC, with a serverless vpc connector.

Comment: Indeed @guillaume blaquiere, when dataproc starts its cluster for pipeline execution, it arbitrarily connects through this "serverless vpc" connector, it can reach the private database but it's impossible to reach internet resources so far. (1) note we noticed no particular firewall rule preventing outbound connection, nevertheless this configuration is not sufficient to reach Internet .

Comment: (2) Configuring a Cloud NAT seems mandatory in this case, and, definitively solves the issue by forwarding public packets over internet. Now S3 fetching is possible. Thanks for inputs @guillaume blaquiere

Comment: Wait, why do you need a serverless VPC connector with Dataproc? You need a VPC connector only with serverless product, not with Dataproc. And thus, if your dataproc cluster has public IPs, you can reach internet, else, you need cloud nat to reach it

Comment: Yes @guillaume blaquiere, our dataproc cluster is a private instance actually, so NAT was the solution. Suppose we switch to a public instance, how could we reach the private database (without cloud sql proxy as possible, this solutions require the hosting of a proxy which is pain in the ass sorry).

Comment: As described in the #1 point of my answer, your cluster is in your VPC, and so you can access your Cloud SQL database through the private IP (check the firewall rule of course!)

Comment: sure #1 would work for a full private setup, which is not my use case. Also, about the #2 private VPC+NAT setup, note the CDF "preview engine" is not working when it's about fetching internet data (obviously the preview backend is not using my VPC/NAT therefore has not internet connection). 
So now, I'm prototyping a "public" cdf/dataproc cluster : with a public IP, fetching S3 is straightforward but connection to my private database is more challenging. I know the cloud sql proxy solution but such an application-level solution seems overkill to me.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't catch the problem. Your dataproc cluster is composed of Compute Engine node. Each Compute engine has, at least, 1 internal IP address that you put in the VPC of your choice, and, optionally a public IP if you make your cluster public. So, in all cases, if you haven't firewall issues and if you use the same VPC, you can reach your private database from your Cluster. For S3, it depends on the publicity of the cluster.

Comment: You're right @guillaume blaquiere, this setup works fine for pipeline deployment and execution. The point is : pipeline preview is not working with this setup since you can't select or configure the compute profile for preview as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517678/cloud-data-fusion-preview-environment